# Image processing using a-trimmed filter went wrong

Tags: image-processing, filter, octave

I have an assignment I must use a a-trimmed filter with `a(p) = 2` over a 3x3 so this is my code on octave:

```
for(i=2:511),
  for(j=2:511),
    D=NoiseImg(i-1:i+1,j-1:j+1);m=1;
      for k=1:3,for l=1:3,E(m)=D(k,l);m=m+1;end;end;
      El=sort(E);sum=0;
      for n=3:7,
        sum=sum+El(n);
      end;
      P2(i,j)=sum/5;
  end;
end;
```

This is my salt n pepper pic(with 6% salt n 6% pepper)[image]

and here is the output of my filter
[image]

what I am doing wrong or is it ok like that??? Thx in advance.

Comment: Could you explain what would you like your filter to do? Moreover, could you show the code to display the images?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a code equivalent to your intention which works:

```
mInputImage = imread('1.png');
mInputImage = double(mInputImage) / 255;
mInputImage = mean(mInputImage, 3);

numRows = size(mInputImage, 1);
numCols = size(mInputImage, 2);
numPixels = numRows * numCols;

vSaltPixelsIdx      = randi([1, (numPixels)], [round(0.05 * numPixels), 1]);
vPepperPixelsIdx    = randi([1, (numPixels)], [round(0.05 * numPixels), 1]);

mNoisyImage = mInputImage;

mNoisyImage(vSaltPixelsIdx)     = 1;
mNoisyImage(vPepperPixelsIdx)   = 0;

mOutputImage = zeros(numRows, numCols);


for ii = [2:(numRows - 1)]
    for jj = [2:(numCols - 1)]
        mCurrPatch = mNoisyImage((ii - 1):(ii + 1), (jj - 1):(jj + 1));
        vCurrPatch = mCurrPatch(:);
        vCurrPatch = sort(vCurrPatch);

        mOutputImage(ii, jj) = mean(vCurrPatch(3:7));
    end
end


figure();
imshow(mInputImage, [0, 1]);

figure();
imshow(mNoisyImage, [0, 1]);

figure();
imshow(mOutputImage, [0, 1]);
```

Good Luck!